# How do we mathematically apply a Quantum Gate/Operation on a pair of Qbits in a Multi-Qbit system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am trying to understand Quantum Gates and Quantum Operations (I am a layman and my background is CS). What I am conceptually aware of:

Any $N$ Qbit system can be written as a vector of $2^N$ complex numbers, where each complex number is an amplitude for each of the corresponding state. The probability that on measurement we get any state is equal to the square of the corresponding amplitudes.

These amplitudes can be transformed by a set of Gate operations on this $2^N$ Qbit vector. The quantum gates themselves are represented by a set of matrices that 'operate on' this vector. Moreover, there are a subset of Quantum Gates that form a 'Universal Set' of Gates (similar to classical computing). These universal gates can simulate any other Gate and help create any Quantum Circuit. And these Universal Gates need to operate on at most 2 Qbits at a time (just like classical gates).

**Query 1:** While I am aware that how these Gates can be applied to toy examples of 2 Qbit states, assuming $N>3$ (lets say $N=5$ for our example), we are given a vector representing the set of these $N$ Qbits i.e. an amplitude vector of size $2^5=32$.

How do we apply a Gate operation in this Multi-Qbit system? For our example lets say we need to apply a universal gate to Qbit number 1 and 3 (for a pair of some non adjacent Qbits). How do we achieve that?

Can someone please show it with a non trivial worked out example or point out to one (and how it can be generalized for any $N$)? I am struggling with this as most of the examples I read are of 2 Qbit systems/vectors.

Comment: Do you mean *mathematically* or how such an operation is/could actually be *implemented* in the lab?

Comment: @march I mean mathematically how its done in abstract (I am not concerned with the physical part of it as of now)? The doubt I have is we have $N$ Qbits and if we were to choose any pair of Qbits there can be $Nx(N-1)$ Qbit pairs to choose from. Assuming we choose any of the pair (which in my example is say 1 and 3), how do we apply a Gate on them in a multi Qbit vector given to us?

Comment: @march For example Hadamard and Toffoli gate form a universal set of Gates. Hadamard works on a single bit so that isn't much of an issue. Toffoli works on 3 inputs: How do i for an arbitrary triplet of inputs apply a Toffoli gate: say for example: Case 1: Qbits (1, 3, 5) Case 2: Qbits (5, 1, 3) Case 3: Qbits (3, 1, 5) and so on?

Comment: Do you know about tensor products?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I know about tensor products (the basics i.e. only how to create using two matrices).

Comment: Can someone please answer this Q? @NorbertSchuch If possible can you please help.